# How to open a file as sudo from within vim?

Tags: sudo

After opening vim as normal user. Is it possible to open a new file as sudo user? like for example in `:e file`.

Comment: You'll have to start vim with sudo for it to have root privileges.

Comment: @Tumbler41 so it's not possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One workaround is to open the file normally:

```
:e file
```

And then use the [sudo tee trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work) when *writing* the file:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

If you don't have read permission on the file, you're going to need to use sudo to get the file contents into Vim, too.

```
" (If necessary) Create a new, empty buffer
:new

" Read file into the empty buffer
:r !sudo cat file

" Delete first (empty) line
:1d

" Do edits...

" Write file
:w !sudo tee file

" Discard buffer and file contents
:bd!
```

Personally, if I haven't already started making changes to the file, I'd just quit vim and then use [sudoedit](http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/):

```
:qall
sudoedit file
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the [SudoEdit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709) plugin, which defines the commands `SudoRead` and `SudoWrite`, which allow me to read and write with sudo permissions a file I didn't think to open with `sudoedit`.

Comment: And instead of `sudo nvim file`, you can do `nvim file -c SudaRead`